# How does Googlebot know a webserver is not cloaking when it requests a `?_escaped_fragment_=` URL?

Tags: ajax, googlebot, google-crawlers

With regard to Google's AJAX crawling spec, if the server returns *one* thing (namely, a JavaScript-heavy file) for a `#!` URL and something *else* (namely, a "html snapshot" of the page) to Googlebot when the `#!` is replaced with `?_escaped_fragment_=`, that *feels* like cloaking to me. After all, how is Googlebot sure that the server is returning good faith equivalents for both the `#!` and `?_escaped_fragment_=` URLs. Yet this is what the AJAX crawling spec actually tells webmasters to do. Am I missing something? How is Googlebot sure that the server is returning the same content in both cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crawler does not know.  But it never knows even for sites that return plain ol' html either - it is extremely easy to write code that cloaks the site based on http headers used by crawlers or known IP headers.

See this related question:  [How does Google Know you are Cloaking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878364/how-does-google-know-you-are-cloaking)

Most of it seems like conjecture, but it seems likely there are various checks in-place, varying between spoofing normal browser headers and actual real-person looking at the page.

Continuing the conjecture, it certainly wouldn't be beyond the capabilities of programmers at Google to write a form of crawler that actually retrieved what the user sees - after all, they have their own browser that does just that.  It would be prohibitively CPU-expensive to do that all the time, but probably makes sense for the occasional spot-check.